# In Android, is there a way to set flags/ broadcast receivers to affect other applications?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, flags

working on an idea for an app but research is proving difficult to get a straight answer on the subject so I wanted to ask the experts.

**What I want to know it, is there a way within your written code to have a direct effect on other applications?**

3 Examples (To try and make it more clear):

**1)** Adjust something in my app so that whenever I open up an app that starts with N (IE Netflix) the media volume turns to max, or the wifi turns on.

**2)** Adjust something in my app so that whenever I receive an email to my yahoo account (using the yahoo mail app) a toast comes up that says, "DANGER WILL ROBINSON!".

**3)** Adjust something in my app so that whenever I open up the application facebook, a notification bar icon appears.

**Essentially, I am trying to change something within the phone (a Setting, a toast, whatever) whenever another app is opened up via my application's code.**

Ideas? Can this be done? Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add intent-filter in your BroadcastReceiver of your application. Since onReceive()  is always triggered by ACTION but not the name of an app, I think you have to find a specific action in an app which you can use to start your own app.  Check system standard ACTIONs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND). Hope it helps you.

Comment: Excellent, I shall do some research down that road. Thanks!